# how to store the same key for data in single array

Tags: php

Check For Brackets
Current Result:

```
[{"Date":"2019-02-18","type":"Casual Leave","value":0},
 {"type":"Sick Leave","value":0},
 {"type":"Emergency Leave","value":0},
 {"type":"Comp Off","value":0},
 {"Date":"2019-02-19","type":"Casual Leave","value":0},
 {"type":"Sick Leave","value":0},
 {"type":"Emergency Leave","value":0},
 {"type":"Comp Off","value":0}]
```

Expected Result:

```
[{"Date":"2019-02-18",
  "type":"Casual Leave","value":0,
  "type":"Sick Leave","value":0,
  "type":"Emergency Leave","value":0,
  "type":"Comp Off","value":0},
 {"Date":"2019-02-19",
  "type":"Casual Leave","value":0,
  "type":"Sick Leave","value":0,
  "type":"Emergency Leave","value":0,
  "type":"Comp Off","value":0}]
```

Comment: And this not a php array is a js array object .Single object same key may not possible

Comment: How do you intend to specify *which one*  of the types you or values you will select in the second snippet?

Comment: this result i have to send to android front end.they will handle it.

Comment: They definitely __won't__.

Comment: this way, they want the result, can we do it. as i feel, we cannot